# Swift unable to connect multiple buttons via IBAction "Any" but okay via "AnyObject"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I am building an app with 9 buttons. I am trying to connect it to one IBaction below, which does not work (No UI update in assistant editor to let me connect the button and this IBAction code block).

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    print("ButtonPressed")

}
```

[image]

It works however with "AnyObject" after sender.

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    print("ButtonPressed")

}
```

[image]

**Question 1, why is this behavior?**

**Question 2, what is the difference between Any and AnyObject in Swift?**

Based on [swift_documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342), *any* allows objects of various types while *anyObject* allows only objects of the same type. In this case, i believe it means that the sender object has to be of the same type for *any*.

Does this mean connecting multiple buttons is only allowed for buttons of the same type therefore only *anyObject* works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last things first :)

### The Difference

If you look at the description of `Any` and `AnyObject` in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342) you'll find this description:

> - Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.
> - AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.

### Why this behaviour

I'm guessing here but `@IBAction` is part of the [Target-Action](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) pattern used by Apple for communicating between different elements of your app (targets know how to relate to actions). As this pattern predates Swift I'm guessing the `sender` of an action has to be a class for this to work. In Objective C you would use `id`, meaning "Any Class", and in Swift - as we've just found out - the representation of "Something that can be of type any class" is `AnyObject`.

Hope that makes sense and helps you.

Comment: In this case, I guess Xcode should have defaulted a new IBAction to *anyObject*. But the default I get for setting up the first button is *any*.

Comment: hmm, you're right. I don't have the answer for that sorry. Normally I use the "direct" type instead of `Any` or `AnyObject`, meaning that in this case I'd use `UIButton` as a type for my `sender`, just as @vadian describes in his answer. I found these discussions on the Swift development Jira: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2426 and Github https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/4320 but that is about it...sorry

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 the equivalent of `id` in Objective-C has been changed from `AnyObject` to `Any`.

However all UI Elements are objects by definition and `AnyObject` is required for the target / action pattern.

If the sender(s) of the `IBAction` are of the same class (or subclass) you can even specify the `sender` as that class for example:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
```

Comment: By *all buttons*, are you referring to element built by **button** from the object library, regardless of whether it is a text button or an image button?

Comment: In other words: If the sender(s) are of the same class (or subclass) you can specify the sender as that class. This is useful if you need to access properties or methods of that class. I updated the answer,